# c++ unresolved external symbol OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, openssl

For the context, I'm trying to build the TrinityCore solution.

When I'm building the solution I face this error among others:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol
> OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path referenced in function "void
> __cdecl OpenSSLCrypto::threadsCleanup(void)" (?threadsCleanup@OpenSSLCrypto@@YAXXZ)   authserver  C:\Build\src\server\authserver\common.lib(OpenSSLCrypto.obj)    1

I understand that it doesn't find the link to `OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path` from the OpenSSL library. So I checked the properties of the project but it seems ok to me:

"Additionnal Include Directories" found in Properties -> C/C++ -> General:

```
C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\include;
C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\include\openssl;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\server\authserver;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\server\authserver\Authentication;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\server\authserver\Server;
C:\Build\src\server\authserver;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\server\shared;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\server\shared\DataStores;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\server\shared\Dynamic;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\server\shared\Dynamic\LinkedReference;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\server\shared\Networking;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\server\shared\Packets;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\server\shared\Realm;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\server\shared\Secrets;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\server\database;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\server\database\Database;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\server\database\Database\Implementation;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\server\database\Logging;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\server\database\Updater;
C:\Build;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\common;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\common\Asio;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\common\Collision;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\common\Collision\Management;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\common\Collision\Maps;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\common\Collision\Models;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\common\Configuration;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\common\Containers;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\common\Containers\Utilities;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\common\Cryptography;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\common\Cryptography\Authentication;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\common\DataStores;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\common\Debugging;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\common\Encoding;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\common\Hacks;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\common\IPLocation;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\common\Logging;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\common\Metric;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\common\Platform;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\common\Threading;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\common\Time;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\src\common\Utilities;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\dep\argon2;
C:\local\boost_1_78_0;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\dep\fmt\include;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\dep\g3dlite\include;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\dep\zlib;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\dep\recastnavigation\Detour\Include;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\dep\SFMT;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\dep\utf8cpp;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\dep\valgrind;
C:\Trinity\TrinityCore\dep\short_alloc;
%(AdditionalIncludeDirectories);
```

"Additionnal Library Directories" found in Properties -> Linker -> General:

```
%(AdditionalLibraryDirectories);C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\lib
```

"Additionnal Dependencies" found in Properties -> Linker -> Input:

```
..\shared\RelWithDebInfo\shared.lib;
..\database\RelWithDebInfo\database.lib;
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\lib\libmysql.lib;
..\..\common\RelWithDebInfo\common.lib;
..\..\..\dep\argon2\RelWithDebInfo\argon2.lib;
C:\local\boost_1_78_0\lib64-msvc-14.3\libboost_system-vc143-mt-x64-1_78.lib;
C:\local\boost_1_78_0\lib64-msvc-14.3\libboost_filesystem-vc143-mt-x64-1_78.lib;
C:\local\boost_1_78_0\lib64-msvc-14.3\libboost_program_options-vc143-mt-x64-1_78.lib;
C:\local\boost_1_78_0\lib64-msvc-14.3\libboost_iostreams-vc143-mt-x64-1_78.lib;
C:\local\boost_1_78_0\lib64-msvc-14.3\libboost_regex-vc143-mt-x64-1_78.lib;
C:\local\boost_1_78_0\lib64-msvc-14.3\libboost_locale-vc143-mt-x64-1_78.lib;
..\..\..\dep\fmt\RelWithDebInfo\fmt.lib;
..\..\..\dep\g3dlite\RelWithDebInfo\g3dlib.lib;
..\..\..\dep\recastnavigation\Detour\RelWithDebInfo\Detour.lib;
..\..\..\dep\zlib\RelWithDebInfo\zlib.lib;
..\..\..\dep\SFMT\RelWithDebInfo\sfmt.lib;
kernel32.lib;
user32.lib;
gdi32.lib;
winspool.lib;
shell32.lib;
ole32.lib;
oleaut32.lib;
uuid.lib;
comdlg32.lib;
advapi32.lib;
C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\libcrypto.lib;
C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\lib\libssl.lib
```

Also the `OSSL_PROVIDER_set_default_search_path` seems to be inside `provider.h` which is a file found in `C:\Program Files\OpenSSL-Win64\include\openssl` which seems included in the project. What is also weird is that I can "ctrl-click" on it and it opens up in visual studio, so it seems to have a reference to it.

Can someone help me or explain me what is wrong with my setup ?

Thank you

Comment: Does the solution platform match the library bitnes (x64)? And is the proper configuration selected? I mean, you might look at one configuration properties and build the other. I know, stupid suggestion, but it happens sometimes

Comment: Yes both are x64. Thier is no stupid question and it gave me an idea: the configuration I updated was the one of the project "worldserver" as it is where the error happen. But it mention "common.lib" in the error message and their is an other project called "common". I checked on the properties of this project but their is no "Linker" panel but a "Librarian" one. What does it mean ? Should I update properties of "worldserver" or "common" ?

Comment: what version of openssl is this? https://github.com/haproxy/haproxy/issues/1756#issuecomment-1162647403

Comment: @starball It's Win64 OpenSSL v3.2.0

Comment: under (recursively) the directories where the parts of the relevant OpenSSL installation are, are there any subdirectories named `lib64`?

Answer (score 0):

libcrypto.lib is for use with the DLL: github.com/openssl/openssl/issues/11156

Either:

- Try using libcrypto_static.lib instead of libcrypto.lib.

or

- Include the DLL for libcrypto